flutter how to calculate widget size from pixel?
For example, 100px for web:
How to convert it to a width in flutter?
SizedBox(width: 100);

100 here in flutter is logical.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For example with iPhone 12, technical specifications res is 1170 x 2532 pixels
-> Width = 1170px
-> Height =  2532px
Then measure by Dart code run on iPhone 12:
final logicalWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // 390.0
final logicalHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; // 844.0
final devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio; // 3.0

so real px width (1170) = logical width (390.0) x device pixel ratio (3.0)
-> 100px on iPhone 12 on flutter = 100/3.0 = 33.3

double pxValue = 100; // Your web pixel value
double logicalWidth = pxValue / MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

SizedBox(width: logicalWidth);

MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio provides the ratio between logical and physical pixels on the device.
Dividing the pxValue by this ratio gives a rough estimate of the logical width in Flutter.
